# How to retrieve a value of an attribute from the XML stored across multiple rows using Oracle-Xquery?

Tags: oracle11g, xquery

We are using Oracle 11g database with XMLDB installation. We are having table with XMLType columns. The structure of the XML will be same for all the rows in a table. The table will have other fiedls also.

Now I want to retrieve only the values of the particular node's attribute values from all the rows as a string with some other relational fields. The table columns retrieved can be like TemplateId, TemplateVid,TemplatepartId.

The structure of the XML can be as follows:

```
<Template ID=1000 VID=1>
  <TemplateParts>
    <Template ID="4000" VID="1"/>
    <Template ID="4001" VID="1"/>
  </TemplateParts>
</Template>
```

So the table will have data for Template with TemplateId,Vid and TemplateXML. The TemplateXML field is an XMLType field. Now I want to retrieve all the TemplateId,Vid and its refereced template partIds as an XML table. The output should be as follows:

```
TemplateId - TemplateVid - TemplatePartId - TemplatepartVid
1000           1             4000             1
1000           1             4001             1
```

So anybody comes up with a correct Xquery for the above requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my earlier comment, I have managed to get the IDs and VIDs which is stored under the Node /Template/TemplateParts/Template from xmltype column of all the rows. The query is as follows:

```
select distinct  x.value as TemplatePartId,Y.Value as Vid from 
TempVersion t ,
xmltable('/Template/TemplateParts/Template' passing t.CONTENT columns  value    varchar2(10) path '@ID' ) x,
  xmltable('/Template/TemplateParts/Template' passing t.CONTENT columns  value varchar2(10) path '@VID' ) y
    order by TemplatePartId;
```

If sombody know better format,please post your sample query. I need as a normal query as the above format is not supported by my ORM tool. If you look at the above query you can notice that the XMLTable expression is to be placed after the From clause. This gives trouble when I try to form this query through my LLBLGen ORM tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear but to start you off and hopefully get you some additional comment from the wider XQuery community on StackOverflow here is a quick example. Hope this helps :)

```
xquery version "1.0";

<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<table>
<tr><th>TemplateId</th><th>TemplateVid</th><th>TemplatePartId</th><th>TemplatepartVid</th></tr>
{
    let $sample as element()* := (<root><Template ID="1000" VID="1"><TemplateParts><Template ID="4000" VID="1" /><Template ID="4001" VID="1" /></TemplateParts></Template></root>)
    for $e in $sample/Template
    return
        for $tp in $e/TemplateParts/Template
        return 
            (<tr><td>{data($e/@ID)}</td><td>{data($e/@VID)}</td><td>{data($tp/@ID)}</td><td>{data($tp/@VID)}</td></tr>)
}
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you mistaken my requirement. I need to fectch the data stored in a relational table (of Oracle11g) column of datatype 'XMLType'. The table will have noraml columns (int,varchar2,etc) and a column of datatype 'XMLType' which contains the structure as mentioned in my mail. My requirement is retrieve only the TemplatePartId and its Vids from all the rows. Anyway with some help from my collegue, I have manage to do it. Please see it my answer.

Comment: I think you have to admit the requirement was not clear..... as I said. Anyway good luck with the rest.

Comment: Hello Mactwixs, Yes I might not have explained correctly in my initial post. Some of the terminologies like table,xml table,xquery might make somebody think about the pure XML-Xquery usage. Anyway thanks for your suggestion as it might still useful for another user.